# VBA copy style from template Application.OrganizerCopy does not update the activedocument.styles(Style.NameLocal) & list local styles

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

I am trying to have a set of ms-Word documents that use the same formatting (from a document template).
**EDIT**:
I create the documents using the template as suggested by [@timothy-rylatt] and [@john-korchok], but I am still making updates to the styles in the template.  When I use the Style organizer, I see many of the built-in styles.  When I try to update a document that uses the template, I use `vba` to copy in a list of named styles ***from the template***.

I have two problems:

1. When I copy in the styles using either the style organizer or the `vba` below,
   the styles in the target document do not update (at least the numbering, borders, background colors, etc.
2. `If` I am going to do style element by element updates (right indent, left indent, numbering Base Style, ... `Then`, I would like to update only the styles actually stored in the target document.  The second segment of `vba` below lists the styles, but *all* of the visible styles, not just the ones in the current document.

### The VBA code to copy in a single style

It does not update the instances that use the style in the target document.

```vb
Private Sub moveOneStyle(styleName As String, _
        fromFile As String, _
        toFile As String)
'
' moveOneStyle
'  styleName: is the style to copy
'  fromFile: is usually a word template file .dotx or .dotm
'      (open the from file, and then use that fromDoc.FullName)
'  toFile: is usually the Application.ActiveDocument.FullName
'
'
    On Error GoTo record
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=fromFile, _
            Destination:=tof, _
            name:=styleName, _
            Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles
    GoTo done
record:
    Debug.Print styleName
done:
    'On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

### The VBA code to list the styles in the current document

Now, I understand that most of the time, this will be used to retrieve any style name that is in the current document, the template, or a built-in (in that order), but I cannot figure out how to get only the ones that are in the current document.  See the code below for the `here a miracle occurs`.  I am looking for the miracle.

```vb
Private Sub listAllStyles()
    Dim d As Word.Document
    Dim sty As Word.Style
    Dim styName As Variant
    Dim r As Word.Range
    Dim Inuse As String

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set d = Application.ActiveDocument
    Set r = d.Range()
    r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each sty In d.Styles
        styName = sty.NameLocal
        On Error GoTo StyError
        ' if sty. is from this document
        ' here a miracle occurs
        If sty.Inuse Then Inuse = "True" Else Inuse = "False"
        r.text = CStr(styName) + " inuse= " + Inuse + vbCrLf
        r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        GoTo StyNext
StyError:
        Debug.Print styName
StyNext:
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next sty
    Set d = Nothing
    Set sty = Nothing
    Set r = Nothing
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: “ I cannot figure out how to get only the ones that are in the current document” - all of the styles exist in the document, both built-in and custom.

Comment: Instead of copying the styles in from the template you should be creating your documents from the template - that is what templates are for.

Comment: Unless background colors and borders are assigned to specific styles, those attributes will not be copied. Document borders and backgrounds are not styles. For numbering, you must copy both the styles and the list style that organizes the numbering. But first, follow Timothy's advice: create new documents from the template.

Comment: Thanks to @timothy-rylatt and john-korchok.  I updated the question to say that I am using a template, but then I make changes to the template and would like reflect those updates in the document.

Comment: "I would like to update only the styles actually stored in the target document" - just to repeat myself ***all*** of the styles are stored in the target document. There is no magical hidden style storage. When you create the document everything from the template except building-blocks and macros is copied into the document. This includes the built-in styles.

Comment: I suggest that you also look up the [help text for NameLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.style.namelocal)

Comment: Thank you @timothy-rylatt for the Name Local issue.  yes that is good to avoid (the names change whenever the language change).  The click box in the answer I suggested get around the naming issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### With VBA

I found a way to do what I wanted to do, *i.e.*, update my styles from the document template.

```vb
Private Sub linktemplate()
'
' linktemplate Macro
'
'
    With ActiveDocument
        .AttachedTemplate = _
            "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\projectTemplate.dotx"
        .UpdateStylesOnOpen = False
        .UpdateStylesOnOpen = True
        .UpdateStylesOnOpen = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I used the sequence of (false, true, false) because the styles update on the false -> to true transition.

***Note Bene (N.B.)*** These steps will only update the styles that are **In use** in the template.

#### Without VBA

Now, if you want to do this without vba, from https://office-watch.com/2018/automatically-update-document-styles-in-microsoft-word/ (Office Watch)

Quoting the relevant parts:

> Deep in Microsoft Word is the choice “Automatically Update Document > Styles”.  What does that do and which documents are affected?
>
> There are several similarly worded options to do with ‘Style’ and
> ‘Automatic’ so let’s be clear … we’re talking about File | Options |
> Add-ins | Manage | Templates | Go | Templates and Add-ins | Templates
> … we did say ‘deep’ inside Word.
>
> [image: A screen shot of what you see when you get there]

In place of Normal, you can put your project template.  And when it says, "Automatically Update Document Styles," what it means is to update the current document styles *from* the template.

Check the update box, and then uncheck it, or the document will keep updating whenever you open the document (although maybe that is what you wanted).